# Skip One Node - Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

So I have an application in Python and I used Watson Conversation.
However, I've been encountering some challenges specially on Dialogue.
It works on "try it out" however when it comes to the application it doesn't accept skip user input

Dialogue

Watson response/ User input

Conversation_start = " " / (hello)

Node 1 : Check for weather intent / (check for the weather on this location)

Node1.1(child) : computation / (ok) ///// HOW TO SKIP THIS /////

Node1.1.1(child) : print computation / (Thank you)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't share any code or workspace information. My guess is that you are not sending the dialog context back to the Conversation service. The service has a stateless API. In order to continue in a dialog, it needs the context of the ongoing chat.

I have written a [Python-based tool to work with the Conversation service](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool). You can also use it to test the dialog. Check the code to see how the context is retrieved and then sent back.

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: basically i'm trying to update context when using skip_user_input

Comment: The workspace in this repo shows how to do that: https://github.com/data-henrik/slack-chatbot-database-watson However, if it works in the Conversation UI, but not in your app, then the context handling is not right.

Comment: Thanks a lot I finally able to get it. The problem is I'm parsing context[] instead of response[context]